# what is equivalent layout (asp.net core) in spring?

Tags: html, spring, hibernate, asp.net-core, layout

i am beginner in the spring and i try to create a simple layout with child view in the spring using hibernate.
but i can't understand how to create it.
please help me.:D

simple layout in asp.net core

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zxx">
<head>
    <title>ProDent - Dentist Template</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="ProDent dentist template" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="prodent, dentist, creative, html" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link href="/img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />
    <link href="~/css/fontiran.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Google Font -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Stylesheets -->
    <link href="~/css/persianDatepicker-default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/css/RegistrationStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/flaticon.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/owl.carousel.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/animate.css" />
    <!-- rtl -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/rtl.css" />
    @RenderSection("StylesOnViews", false) <!--here rendering styles on child views-->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Page Preloder -->
    <div id="preloder">
        <div class="loader"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Page Preloder End -->
    <!-- Header section -->
    @(await Component.InvokeAsync("HeaderSiteComponent"))
    <!-- Header section end -->

    @RenderBody() <!--here rendering child view-->

    <!-- Footer top section -->
    @(await Component.InvokeAsync("footerSiteComponent"))
    <!-- Footer top section end -->

    <!--====== Javascripts & Jquery ======-->
    <script src="/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/circle-progress.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/FactsScripts.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/persianDatepicker.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("ScriptsOnViews", false) <!-- here rendering scripts on child views --> 
</body>
</html>
```

and my child view :
all of this html file replaced with @RenderBody in layout

```html
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Login";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_defaultLayout.cshtml";
}

<section class="page-info-section set-bg" data-setbg="img/page-info-bg/1.jpg">
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="text-center">ورود کاربران</h2>
    </div>
</section>


<div class="limiter">
    <div class="container-login100">
        <div class="wrap-login100">
            <div class="login100-form-title" style="background-image: url(img/dentists.jpg);">
                <span class="login100-form-title-1">ورود کاربران</span>
            </div>
            <form class="login100-form validate-form">
                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-26" data-validate="لطفا نام کاربری خود را وارد کنید!">
                    <span class="label-input100">نام کاربری</span>
                    <input class="input100" type="text" name="username" placeholder="نام کاربری خود را وارد کنید">
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-18" data-validate="لطفا رمز عبور خود را وارد کنید!">
                    <span class="label-input100">رمز عبور</span>
                    <input class="input100" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="رمز عبور خود را وارد کنید">
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-sb-m w-full p-b-30 text-right" dir="rtl">
                    <div>
                        <a href="#" class="txt1">رمز عبور خود را فراموش کرده اید؟</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contact100-form-checkbox">
                        <input class="input-checkbox100" id="ckb1" type="checkbox" name="remember-me">
                        <label class="label-checkbox100" for="ckb1">مرا بخاطر بسپار</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                    <button class="login100-form-btn">وارد شوید</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> @(await Component.InvokeAsync("HeaderSiteComponent"))
>
> and
>
> @(await Component.InvokeAsync("footerSiteComponent"))

in the layout are header(menu items and..etc) and footer.
menu items in the header component load form dataBase and also i can send data to this component..

what is this equivalent in spring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found answer this question :
for create a layout or component i should create fragment in spring using thymeleaf.
for example :
1-create footer html file and called  footer.html

```html
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>
    <footer th:fragment="footer">
        <p>your content....</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

> notice : only attention to footer tag because only footer will be
> insert into homePage moreover you should call footer by name that put front th:fragment

2- now you may call footer in homePage.
see following code :

```html
<body>
...
<div th:insert="fragments/footer :: footer"></div>
</body>
```

more information :

> [https://attacomsian.com/blog/thymeleaf-fragments#:~:text=A%20fragment%20in%20Thymeleaf%20is,repeated%20used%20on%20multiple%20pages](https://attacomsian.com/blog/thymeleaf-fragments#:%7E:text=A%20fragment%20in%20Thymeleaf%20is,repeated%20used%20on%20multiple%20pages).

Answer (score 1):

In your opinion, you should first define a fragment and then set the output format with the following code

```
<body>

<div th:insert="fragments/components :: header"></div>

<div th:replace="fragments/components :: header"></div>

<div th:include="fragments/components :: header"></div>

</body>
```